# Use if else sql statement with two selects

Tags: sql-server

Currently I have the following SQL query

```
DECLARE @UgpEntry VARCHAR(50)

IF (@UgpEntry = -1)
SELECT t1.ItemCode as sapitemcode
     , t1.CodeBars as Barcode
     , t1.ItemName as description
     ,LEFT(t1.ItemName,20) as short_description
     , 
           (select max(p.Price)
        from ITM1 p 
        where p.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode 
          and p.PriceList = 1) as [price_1]
     , CASE t1.VatGourpSa when 'V0' THEN 4 when 'V1' THEN 1 WHEN 'V2' THEN 2 WHEN 'V3' THEN 3 END as TaxCode,t1.U_GRUPOA, t1.U_GRUPOB, t1.U_GRUPOC, t1.UgpEntry

FROM OITM t1
WHERE t1.ItemCode='00004'

ELSE

SELECT t1.ItemCode as sapitemcode
     , t1.CodeBars as Barcode
     , t1.ItemName as description
     ,LEFT(t1.ItemName,20) as short_description
     , (select max(p.Price)
        from ITM9 p 
        where p.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode 
          and p.UomEntry = 1) as [price_1],

           (select max(p.Price)
        from ITM1 p 
        where p.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode 
          and p.PriceList = 1) as [preciocaja]
     , CASE t1.VatGourpSa when 'V0' THEN 4 when 'V1' THEN 1 WHEN 'V2' THEN 2 WHEN 'V3' THEN 3 END as TaxCode,t1.U_GRUPOA, t1.U_GRUPOB, t1.U_GRUPOC, t1.UgpEntry

FROM OITM t1
WHERE t1.ItemCode='00004'
```

What I'm trying to do:

1. If this column t1.UgpEntry from OITM table (already exists and have data) is equal to -1 then
   run the first query.
2. Else run the second query.

What am I doing wrong?

example: this record have UgpEntry = -1

[image]

[image]
this record have  UgpEntry = 5 and have another columns

Answer (score 0):

I just added  **SELECT @UgpEntry = UgpEntry FROM OITM t1 WHERE t1.ItemCode=''** and it works

```
 DECLARE @UgpEntry VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @UgpEntry = UgpEntry FROM OITM t1 WHERE t1.ItemCode='v6p'

IF (@UgpEntry = -1)

SELECT
t1.ItemCode as sapitemcode
     , t1.CodeBars as Barcode
     , t1.ItemName as description
     ,LEFT(t1.ItemName,20) as short_description
     , 
           (select max(p.Price)
        from ITM1 p 
        where p.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode 
          and p.PriceList = 1) as [price_1]
     , CASE t1.VatGourpSa when 'V0' THEN 4 when 'V1' THEN 1 WHEN 'V2' THEN 2 WHEN 'V3' THEN 3 END as TaxCode,t1.U_GRUPOA, t1.U_GRUPOB, t1.U_GRUPOC, t1.UgpEntry

FROM OITM t1
WHERE t1.ItemCode='v6p' and t1.UgpEntry = -1
 
ELSE

SELECT t1.ItemCode as sapitemcode
     , t1.CodeBars as Barcode
     , t1.ItemName as description
     ,LEFT(t1.ItemName,20) as short_description
     , (select max(p.Price)
        from ITM9 p 
        where p.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode 
          and p.UomEntry = 1) as [price_1],

           (select max(p.Price)
        from ITM1 p 
        where p.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode 
          and p.PriceList = 1) as [preciocaja]
     , CASE t1.VatGourpSa when 'V0' THEN 4 when 'V1' THEN 1 WHEN 'V2' THEN 2 WHEN 'V3' THEN 3 END as TaxCode,t1.U_GRUPOA, t1.U_GRUPOB, t1.U_GRUPOC, t1.UgpEntry

FROM OITM t1
WHERE t1.ItemCode='v6p' and t1.UgpEntry > -1
```